Llamar a pagina php via ajax en plugin wordpress
Estoy creando un plugin para wordpress. El plugin me bota un listado de datos
dato 1 [Boton Eliminar]
dato 2 [Boton Eliminar]
Y quiero que cuando presione el boton eliminar se borre el registro en la base de datos.
tengo un código en listado.php:
function deleteTC(){
     
      if(isset($_POST['info'])){
        $info= $_POST['info'];
        $objRegistro = new cRegistro;
        echo $objRegistro->borrarRegistroTC("{$wpdb->prefix}TipoDeCambio",'codtc',$info);
        
       
      }
    }
    //adicionamos la accion al ajax
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_deleteTC', 'deleteTC' ); 
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_deleteTC', 'deleteTC' );

Y en un archivo Javascript
$('.btnBorrarTC').click( function (){    
        var info = $(this).attr("data-info");        
        var urlBR = $(location).attr("origin") +'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        alert(urlBR);

        $.ajax({
            url : urlBR,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action  : 'deleteTC',
                info    : info
            },
            success:function(r){
                if(r == 1){
                    alert("Correcto");
                } else {
                    alert("No se ha podido borrar");
               }
            }
        });

lo malo está en que primero me salía "No se ha podido votar". Y ahora me sale https://crisav.com.pe/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 BAD REQUEST.
agradezco sus comments.

No haz llamado a la variable global $wpdb, usa global $wpdb;

Hola! sí la llamo dentro de la funcion borrarRegistroTC (clase) /funcion borrar registro en la tabla/
function borrarRegistroTC($tabla, $columna, $valor){
            $cadSQL = sprintf('delete from %s where %s = %s',$tabla, $columna,$valor);        
            return $wpdb->delete(
                $tabla,
                array(
                    $columna => $valor,
                )
            );


Actualiza tu pregunta con el codigo completo, por favor lee [ask] y si puedes haz un try catch al momento de llamar a tu codigo y activa el wp debug para intentar averiguar cual es el problema, tal y como esta tu codigo es complicado saber que falla.

El código de error 400 indica un problema del lado del cliente. Revisa por favor la consola del navegador.
